# What's the difference between Debug.log() and print() function?

Tags: c#

```
Debug.Log("Hello there!");
print("Hello there");
```

Both of the statements display the same output on the console, so what's the difference?

Comment: Is this for C# inside `Unity`?

Comment: `print(string)` is not part of .NET, are you using some other library, or framework on top of .net like Unity or Mono?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this in unity.

Comment: If you don't inherit from monobehavior, print() will not work. debug.log() does not require monobehavior

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being closed. The linked question is about Console.WriteLine vs MonoBehaviour.Print while this question is about Debug.Log vs MonoBehaviour.Print

Comment: This should answer the question. This is the implementation of print.
`public static void print(object message) => Debug.Log(message);`

Answer (score 5):

In native .NET Framework, neither of your examples exist.  The closest functionality would be via either `System.Diagnostics.Debug` or `System.Diagnostics.Trace`.

If you're talking about Unity then behavior is **identical**:

> Logs message to the Unity Console (identical to Debug.Log).

[source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour-print.html)